# How can I create a Drupal page with an automated feed for all the events?

Tags: civievent, drupal

I would like to create an automated feed for all the event we create in CiviEvent, and want to show that on a themed drupal page. I want to feed all info, image that we create during event craetion and a button to register.

Is that something easily achievable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the existing Event feeds?  Go to Events > Manage Events and you'll see icons and help for iCalendar, HTML & RSS feeds. You'll need to look at how you display those feeds but the data about events is there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option, depending on your set up, would be Drupal Views, there's detail in the documentation

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/